# Is there a way to initialize or modify a list that allows to reference previous values?

Tags: r, list, data-structures

I want to store non-rectangular data in a structure, e.g. in a `list`.

Referencing previous data works using a `tibble`, e.g. like this:

```
dat <- tibble(a = 2, 
              b = list(c(a + 1, a + 2)),
              c = list(tibble(a = a, b = 3)))
```

Note that because `tibble` does not allow `tibble` in columns (otherwise the data would not be rectangular), we have to wrap the `tibble` in a list and `dat$c` does not return the `tibble`, for that we need `dat$c[[1]]`.

The latter problem can be solved with a `list`.

```
dat2 <- list(a = 2, 
             b = c(3, 4), 
             c = tibble(a = 2, b = 3))
```

However, now I can't construct the data element with reference to previous entries:

```
dat2 <- list(a = 2, 
             b = c(a + 1, a + 2), 
             c = tibble(a = a, b = 3))
> Error: object 'a' not found
```

My question: Is there a way to construct a non-rectangular data structure that does support construction by reference to previous entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lst()` instead:

```
lst(a = 2, 
    b = c(a + 1, a + 2), 
    c = tibble(a = a, b = 3))

$a
[1] 2

$b
[1] 3 4

$c
# A tibble: 1 × 2
      a     b
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     2     3
```

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! `lst` is in the package `tibble` btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `a = (a <- 2)` for the reference

```
dat <- tibble(
    a = (a<-2),
    b = list(c(a + 1, a + 2)),
    c = list(tibble(a = a, b = 3))
)
```

and you will see

```
> str(dat)
tibble [1 x 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ a: num 2
 $ b:List of 1
  ..$ : num [1:2] 3 4
 $ c:List of 1
  ..$ : tibble [1 x 2] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
  .. ..$ a: num 2
  .. ..$ b: num 3
```